# Is there a term for the point/line/curve division of concavity of a surface in three dimensions?

Tags: terminology

*Point of Inflection* is the name given to the location at which a two dimensional curve changes from concave up to concave down.

Is there a similarly defined term or concept in three dimensions where the division need not be a single point?

for instance the concavity of
$z = cos(\sqrt{x^2 +y^2})$

seems to change when $ z= 0 $ but this results in circles.

Comment: Do you mean a [saddle point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point)?

Comment: @GitGud I don't think so. the jacobian at a saddle point is nonzero, whereas the first derivative vanishes at at inflexion point (and so does the second). I think OP is talking about a point where the jacobian and hessian vanish (or are degenerate). If so I don't know of any standard terminology

Comment: or maybe a degenerate critical point ?

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki that _sounds_ right, but I've been out of working with any of this stuff in school for years and to be honest I'm having a little difficulty getting my head back around this.